# Meteor.loginWithPassword not working with username with @ character

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a user in database with following credentials:

```json
{
    "_id": "zTHv8yqPSm3pmi4So",
    "emails": [{"address": "someemail@example.com", "verified": true}],
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2b$10$L6HXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo1IjZEx6.PBxfOeQHqS."
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ ]
        }
    },
    "username": "some@username",
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "Example",
        "lastName": "User",
    }
}
```

When I try to login user with username it says user not found:

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword("some@username", "123456", function(error) {
    console.log(error.reason); 
});
```

It works fine for email but not for username.

I want flexibility to login user with either of email or username

Comment: Your user record in the database doesn't have a password. It looks quite wrong. It's missing a service field with an encrypted password in it. I think the better question is why on earth would this work for email? Maybe you discovered a bug in meteor, because no one should be allowed to log in based on the record you show.

Comment: You can actually create users without passwords, so it requires the user to first set the password via confirmation email or passwort reset email. This is very well documented in the [Accounts docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html)

Comment: your db has `"username": "some@username",` but your login attempt is using `someusername`. Is that the issue or is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: its a typo, sorry

Answer (score 3):

The API `Meteor.loginWithPassword` actually takes a "selector" as first argument:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword

> `Meteor.loginWithPassword(selector, password, [callback])`
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> `selector` Object or String
>
> Either a string interpreted as a username or an email; or an object with a single key: `email`, `username` or `id`.

In your case you use the string form, and let Meteor try to guess whether it is a username or an email.

But since your username contains an "@" character, this misleads Meteor into interpreting it as an email:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%401.12.1/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L33-L38

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword = (selector, password, callback) => {
  if (typeof selector === 'string')
    if (!selector.includes('@'))
      selector = {username: selector};
    else
      selector = {email: selector};
```

That is why when you try with the email it works fine, but fails for the username containg the "@".

And the simple solution is to explicitly tell Meteor that you target the username (and not an email, despite the "@"):

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword({
        username: "some@username"
    },
    "123456",
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.reason); 
    }
);
```

Now, if I am trying to guess further your objective, you want your user to be able to provide either their email or username as login identifier, without explicitly telling which it is? (Like a kind of "omni" login id input)

In that case, unfortunately you will have to detect yourself whether it is an email or username. If the latter really follows a pattern like "some@username", you can try to detect that the domain is incomplete (no extension).

But if any of your user *did* register a username which really looks like an email (e.g. "some@user.name"), then you may not be able to differentiate them.

Even worse, some user may choose a username that is exactly the email address of another user! In that case, how to tell which one is trying to log in?

IMHO, this then becomes much trouble for marginally improved UX. Either prevent usernames containing "@", i.e. enforce a rule that enables you telling the difference, or provide a way for the user to explicitly tell if it is an email or username when it is ambiguous (e.g. it can be some radios to tell which type it is; it can still contain an "auto" mode for when the login id is unambiguous).

BTW we could also imagine performing a 2 steps login attempt: first as is, then if username contains an "@", explicitly as a username as described above. But we may still fall into the above described worst case scenario...